# unable to install graphlab create on windows8

Tags: graphlab

GraphLab Create Launcher Installation Error in Windows 8:

> There was an error creating the “gl-env” conda environment

#### Also  i tried the manual install.

It was failing in step

```
conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0
```

Comment: could you please add steps as well, which will help SO member to understand and reproduce issue if any.

Comment: I've formatted your post to make it easier to read. Please [edit] your post and tell us _how_ `conda create` failed.

Comment: Also i tried to install graph lab create using the manual version.
C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda2\Scripts>conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.
0

CondaVerificationError: The package for bokeh located at C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda
2\pkgs\bokeh-0.11.1-py27_0
appears to be corrupted. The path 'Scripts/bokeh-script.py-server'
specified in the package manifest cannot be found.

ClobberError: This transaction has incompatible packages due to a shared path.
  packages: defaults::notebook-4.1.0-py27_2, defaults::qtconsole-4.2.0-py27_1
  path: 'menu/jupyter.ico'

Answer (score 0):

Try creating conda environment vertually.